# Laravel Nova uploaded image file not showing on staging environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have deployed a laravel application which is using the Nova admin for backend management on  Bluehost VPS account. I have creates a symlink between storage and public as recommend in the laravel documentation.

I have set up a resource for uploading images like so

```
Avatar::make('Image')->onlyOnIndex(),

Image::make('Image')->disk('public')
->path('item-category')->required()->hideFromIndex()
```

I am using the public disk for storage with the filesystem disk configuration like so

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

On my local system, I am able to see the actual image displayed but on the staging the image is uploaded successfully but does not display because the image is not found
[image]

The record is stored in the db like so
[image]

Why does this same configuration work on my local dev system but not on the staging server? Spent the best part of my morning trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the artisan command `php artisan storage:link`, that will create a symlink from your public folder to the storage folder.